# Search variables in SQLite3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a login system using bcrypt and SQLite, all is working except for this part, I try to search the username using a variable, however when I run the code and input Developer 02 (which is a user on the database) it returns "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 12 supplied." but when I simply specify the username (username='Developer 02') in the sql command it works

```
sql = ''' SELECT password FROM user_data WHERE username=? '''

username = input('Input username: ')
password = bytes(input('Input Password: '), encoding='utf-8')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql, username)
```

Comment: Try `cur.execute(sql, (username,))`. Note trailing comma.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I have no clue if it "worked" but I didn't get the error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JustinEzequiel answered the question in a comment

"Try `cur.execute(sql, (username,))`. Note trailing comma."

This worked perfectly, many thanks to him